# How to make my mailchimp form be consistent across desktop & mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp to manage subscribers to my company's email list. Mailchimp provides embeddable code to use for embedding on to websites. I am using wordpress and the theme is Shopkeeper.

My problem is that when I use their code the input field stretches the entirety of the screen. It looks fine on mobile but on desktop, not so much. I modified the code to have the text input field have a width of 50% but with that, the input field looks too small on mobile.

Check this page on both desktop and mobile to see what I mean:
https://www.californiabeardco.com/summer-giveaway/

How can I modify the following to have a good looking input field on both mobile and desktop?

```
<center>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//californiabeardco.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=410a760d612d262807bb8eb57&amp;id=5d976982af" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <input type="email" value="email address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" style="width:50%;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_410a760d612d262807bb8eb57_5d976982af" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">

</form>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
input#mce-EMAIL {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

This will make the width of the input field on devices below 992px to 100% and devices above 992px will be 50%

Comment: I added that code to the 'custom code' section of the 'appearance' section on wordpress, but the input field on mobile is still the same

Comment: I see! you can try adding "!important" to the width. 

For example:

input#mce-EMAIL {
width: 100% !important;
}

Comment: Perfect, looks great on both mobile and desktop. Thanks!